# Что за Qt-version?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Установил я Qt.

Не могу создать проект из-за того, что нет какой-то Qt-version.

Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно попробовать перезапустить креатор и нужно убедиться, что Qt стоит. Креатор не обязан быть вместе с Qt, т.к. можно много версий Qt на одной машине держать

Comment: Просит валидный кит под widget app, скорее всего проблема в qt-versions. Хотя я не уверен

Comment: Перезапускал. Ничего.

Comment: Kit = Qt + Компилятор + Отладчик. Нужно проверить что установлена хоть какая-нибудь версия Qt. Кст, какая ОС?

Comment: Elementary OS. Был установлен лишь qt creator..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас, скорее всего, нет самого Qt. В старые добрые времена был sdk, теперь надо ставить все по отдельности.

**1. Ставим Creator**

C этим шагом вы, очевидно, уже справились. Если что, новые версии можно брать [здесь](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/).

**2. Ставим компилятор и отладчик**

Как я понял у вас линукс. Можете поставить компилятор и отладчик из репозитория. Скажем, gcc и gdb

**3. Ставим QT**

Скачиваем нужную версию [отсюда](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/). Можно держать сразу несколько версий, если необходимо.

На этом этапе, скорее всего, qt creator сам подхватит все необходимое. Если вдруг нет, то пройдитесь по вкладке Build & Run и настройте все там.